# React native application when run from terminal cannot debug in safari

Tags: react-native, webview, ios-simulator

When React native application is run from terminal using

> npx react-native run-ios

Cannot debug webview from safari. Safari develop menu does not show the simulator in the devices .

Answer (score 0):

I could not debug the application in safari when run using command

> npx react-native run-ios.

But when I tried running the application using Xcode ,simulator was available in

safari develop menu. To debug your web url you need to go to

safari>develop>simulator name> web url